# How to highlight an image area by color with only Qt?

Tags: c++, image, qt, vector, computer-vision

I need to highlight neighboring pixels by color using the Qt (without OpenCV). If, as in one line, it’s quite clear, then the vertical action algorithm for me is still a mystery. Is there any open source project that is not too large to be spied on?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result, I figured it out myself. This can be done by applying a recursive function that examines neighboring cells, ignoring the processed ones.

```
void Worker::fill(QPoint point) {
    QColor pointColor = QColor(image.pixel(point));
    if (ignore.contains(point)) {
        return;
    } else if (compare(templColor, pointColor)) {
        ignore.insert(point);
        image.setPixelColor(point.x(), point.y(), fillColor);
        QList<QPoint> bounding = border(point);
        QList<QPoint>::iterator iter;
        for (iter = bounding.begin(); iter != bounding.end(); iter++) {
            fill(*iter);
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Already examined cells are entered in `ignore` set container. It is used to prevent looping on cell re-processing. The full source code is freely available in [this](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/qt-magic-wand-tool) repository